# Can't run Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have created small app which is using **Node.js** on backend and Angular.js. Locally it's working fine without error. **When I deployed it to Heroku I have get these from logs**:

```
2014-12-30T18:36:14.157309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-12-30T18:36:15.949841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2014-12-30T18:36:17.059157+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-12-30T18:36:17.059201+00:00 app[web.1]: > contacts-app@1.1.0 start /app
2014-12-30T18:36:17.059203+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2014-12-30T18:36:17.059205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-12-30T18:36:18.091349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-12-30T18:36:18.107630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "contacts-app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "author": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

server.js file

```
var express = require('express'),
    api     = require('./api'),
    users   = require('./accounts'),
    app     = express();

app
    .use(express.static('./public'))
    .use(users)
    .use('/api', api)
    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        if (!req.user) {
            res.redirect('/login');
        } else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');
        }
    });
```

App directory structure
[image: App directory structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start listening on the Express app:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I can't see it in your code.

[Reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen)